# NuGet throws "Unable to satisfy package dependency constraints" but no dependency is required in the package description

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to update the following nuget packages :

- [System.Collections.Immutable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable)
- [System.Reflection.Metadata](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.Metadata) (which only requires the previous package)

When doing so, I get an

> "Unable to satisfy package dependency constraints"

error. But :

- On the System.Collections.Immutable package page, it is mentionned that no dependency is required
- Even after I've forced the update of the first one by selecting the `Ignore dependency` option, I still get the error for the second package

If I force both updates, when running my code,

> the System.Reflection.Metadata raises an EntryPointNotFoundException : unable to find "ReadFile" entry point in api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll.

For now, I would like to now why I can't update my packages in a normal way before investigating further the second problem.

I'm working on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2015 RC and with NuGet 3.0

Thanks in advance for your help !

**EDIT** : I'm not sure this is a duplicate because in my case I get the error with a package which doesn't require any dependency.